# Getting positional location of android device respective of other android devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, location

I want to create a way to let users communicate with phones `in front` or `behind them` or `right of them` or `left of them`. Although this cannot be achieved with GPS, I was hoping to use Bluetooth to achieve this effect. I know there are algorithms that can see how far a device is from another device based on Bluetooth signal strength, but I did not see anything about giving positional direction. I have looked into other ways to track users using uwb signal but have not been able to get something that would give positional direction.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to get positional direction using Bluetooth, you can only get how near you're from other devices. However, you could try to do some Bluetooth triangulation, but I'm not sure if that's even possible.

In case Bluetooth triangulation is possible, I have to say I don't know how to do so and I couldn't guarantee its accuracy.

This answer [Is wifi/bluetooth Triangulation(not trilateration) using a mobile device possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642396/is-wifi-bluetooth-triangulationnot-trilateration-using-a-mobile-device-possibl) will give you some hints about triangulation.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to figure out how to distance between bluetooth devices and used that in my app instead!